# Copy shapes from one Excel sheet to another with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to copy and past a shape from one excel worksheet to another without shifting its position on this sheet. The following code allows me copy and paste the shape from one place to another but it shifts the position of my shape around

```
Set sh = WshSrc.Shapes("Rectangle 2")

    For Each WshTrg In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      If WshTrg.Name <> "Base" And WshTrg.Name <> "Format" Then
        WshTrg.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        WshTrg.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        WshTrg.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        WshTrg.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End If
    Next WshTrg
  Set WshSrc = Nothing

    For Each WshTrg In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      If WshTrg.Name <> "Base" And WshTrg.Name <> "Format" Then
        'sh.Name = WshSrc.Name & "_" & sh.Name
        sh.Copy
        WshTrg.Paste
        End If
        With sh
            .Height = PasteCell.Height
            .Width = PasteCell.Width
            .Top = PasteCell.Top
            .Left = PasteCell.Left
        End With
     Next WshTrg
```

Comment: It is not that easy if the column/row width in both the sheets are not identical. At most what you can do is find the shapes `.TopLeftCell` but then again if the image is not aligned to the borders then that can also become a challenge. Perhaps if you can post a screenshot as to what you want to achive?

Comment: the column /row width in both sheets are the same

Comment: @SiddharthRout .

Comment: `Perhaps if you can post a screenshot as to what you want to achive? – Siddharth Rout 1 hour ago`

Answer (score 0):

```
sh.copy
WshTrg.Paste
Set sh2 = WhsTrg.Shapes(sh.name)
sh2.Left = sh.Left
sh2.Top = sh.Top
```

Comment: i want to paste it to multiple sheets, how do i avoid referencing the sheet name WhsTrg.Shapes(sh.name)

Comment: In that case just loop through the sheets: `For Each sh2 in Worksheets...` and add a condition for sheets you want to paste in: `If sh2.name Like "SomeCondition*" Then`